# The components not only ovelaps another, but it expands out of the background of the components instead of having spaces between components

Tags: html, reactjs, tailwind-css

When I created "Experience" component for portfolio website, I expected to have large gap between components on both desktop and mobile. Although I got what I expected on [desktop](https://imgur.com/a/a1jbaVI) (albeit smaller gap than usual (1st image on 1st link)), on [mobile](https://imgur.com/a/Ykaou2g) not only the component overlaps "Portfolio" component (refering to 3rd image on 2nd link), but it even expand beyond its background (2nd image on 2nd link). I tried to adjust the component with padding and margin but it either changed nothing or worse than before.

App.tsx:

```
import Portfolio from "./components/Portfolio";
import Experience from "./components/Experience";


const App = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <main>
        {/* <Navbar/>
        <Home />
        <About/> */}
        <Portfolio/>
        <Experience/>
      </main>
    </>
  );
}

export default App
```

Portfolio.tsx:

```
import React from "react";

const Portfolio = () => {
    const portfolios = [
        {
            id: 1,
            name: "Lorem Ipsum",
            link: "https://www.lipsum.com/"
        },
        {
            id: 2,
            name: "Lorem Ipsum",
            link: "https://www.lipsum.com/"
        },
        {
            id: 3,
            name: "Lorem Ipsum",
            link: "https://www.lipsum.com/"
        },
    ];

    return (
        <div className="bg-gradient-to-b from-black to-gray-600 w-full text-[#f3f3f3] md:h-screen">
            <div className="max-w-screen-lg p-4 mx-auto flex flex-col justify-center w-full h-full">
                <div className="pb-8">
                    <p className="text-4xl font-bold inline border-b-4 border-gray-500">
                        Portfolio
                    </p>
                    <p className="py-6">Check out some of my work here:</p>
                </div>
                <div className="grid sm:grid-cols-2 md:grid-cols-3 gap-8 px-12 sm:px-0">
                    {portfolios.map(({ id, name, link }) => (
                        <a
                            key={id}
                            href={link}
                            target="_blank"
                            rel="noopener noreferrer"
                        >
                            <div className="shadow-md shadow-gray-500 rounded-lg duration-200 hover:scale-105">
                                <img
                                    src="https://picsum.photos/1000/1000"
                                    className="rounded-[0.375rem_0.375rem_0rem_0rem]"
                                ></img>

                                <p className="flex items-center justify-center py-2">
                                    {name}
                                </p>
                            </div>
                        </a>
                    ))}
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
};

export default Portfolio;
```

Experience.tsx:

```
import React from "react";
import { MdOutlineWorkOutline, MdOutlineSchool } from "react-icons/md";
import { LuSchool, LuBookMarked } from "react-icons/lu";

const Experience = () => {
    const exp = [
        {
            id: 1,
            Icon: MdOutlineWorkOutline,
            title: "Lorem Ipsum",
            sub: "Lorem Ipsum",
        },
        {
            id: 2,
            Icon: MdOutlineSchool,
            title: "Lorem Ipsum",
            sub: "Lorem Ipsum",
        },
        {
            id: 3,
            Icon: LuBookMarked,
            title: "Lorem Ipsum",
            sub: "Lorem Ipsum",
        },
        {
            id: 4,
            Icon: LuSchool,
            title: "Lorem Ipsum",
            sub: "Lorem Ipsum",
        },
        {
            id: 5,
            Icon: LuSchool,
            title: "Lorem Ipsum",
            sub: "Lorem Ipsum",
        },
    ];

    return (
        <div className="bg-gradient-to-b from-gray-600 to-black h-screen text-[#f3f3f3]">
            <div className="max-w-screen-lg mx-auto p-4 flex flex-col justify-center w-full h-full">
                <div>
                    <p className="text-4xl font-bold inline border-b-4 border-gray-500">
                        Experience
                    </p>
                    <p className="py-6">
                        Here are school, course and work experiences:
                    </p>
                </div>

                <div className="py-6">
                    {exp.map(({ id, Icon, title, sub }) => (
                        <div key={id} className="flex flex-col md:flex-row pb-8">
                            <Icon
                                size={50}
                                className="mb-2 mx-auto md:mx-0 md:mb-0"
                            />
                            <div className="flex flex-col items-center md:items-start w-full md:inline md:pl-4">
                                <p className="text-xl font-bold text-center md:text-left">
                                    {title}
                                </p>
                                <p className="text-xl text-center md:text-left">
                                    {sub}
                                </p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    ))}
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
};

export default Experience;
```